# How to make sure a custom list item renders on top when screen size gets smaller

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have created an unordered list with custom bullets, and it seems to have small unwanted behavior.

When the screen size get smaller than 364px, the LI text renders to two lines. At the same time, the custom bullet renders to the second line instead of the first.

How can I change this without changing the behavior on other screen sizes?

Much appreciated!

[image: Example]

```css
#list {
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}

#list ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

#list ul li {
  padding: 0px 0px 10px 40px;
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/20') no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom 12px left 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="list">
  <ul>
    <li><strong>Gratis</strong> omgevingsvergunning check</li>
    <li>Bezoek op locatie</li>
    <li>3D impressie</li>
    <li>Projectbegeleiding</li>
    <li>Bouwvergunningen</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the background position, which is set to be relative to the bottom of your `li` element. If you set your background position like so it should do the trick:

```
background-position: top 12px left 10px;
```

```css
#list {
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}

#list ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

#list ul li {
  padding: 0px 0px 10px 40px;
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/20') no-repeat;
  background-position: top 12px left 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="list">
  <ul>
    <li><strong>Gratis</strong> omgevingsvergunning check</li>
    <li>Bezoek op locatie</li>
    <li>3D impressie</li>
    <li>Projectbegeleiding</li>
    <li>Bouwvergunningen</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why there are four parameters in the style rule, but I'd suggest `background-position: 10px 3px;`.

Comment: background-position: top 12px left 10px; this suggestion positioned every bullet point downwards so they weren't aligned with the text anymore. @isherwood, you're solution worked, thanks! Thanks both for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how to properly respond.